# Unit testing a python 3.x code written for Google AppEngine flexible environment and using Cloud Datastore Api

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to unit test a code which is using cloud datastore api and written for flexible environment? [testbed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting)  seems to be tied up with standard environment and it looks like using [emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) will require launching/closing emulator process which usually is a flaky way for unit tests.

Answer (score -1):

We end up with end to end testing (launch you tests with real db in dev environment, for example) As we having tenant based application, each test run just creates new tenant and all operations performed in scope of this tenant, so, there should no any inconsistency here. In the other hand, such solution is pretty slow.

The solution above, is just the easiest one, I believe here.
Another option would be to split you code on db dependent parts and business logic part. In this case you will test only business logic part, and mock db dependency. But, as we've investigated such solution, we found that we have a lot of code that have one line of db write operation and 1-3 lines of business logic code. So, splitting such code on different levels would be meaningless for testing and maintenance.

I guess, the last option is more generic relatively previous one, is to mock db. For each module that uses db, before test it you should inject mocked database index, that defines some responses. But in this case it is easy to fall in realization testing, instead of behavioral testing, so again that will mean, that such testing becomes quite ineffective.

I guess, this question is more generic about testing approaches, and not about actually datastore itself.

Comment: Tests that we are automating using unit tests are more of integration tests in a sense that more then one class / library is involved. But as each developer will be writing code on his local machine, we are looking for a solution that works end to end on users machine instead of setting up a project on google cloud. Another reason is as you mentioned speed. I managed to get emulator working with unit test as below

Comment: Hey @rizTaak, can you show how you managed to get emulator working, thanks

Comment: I followed the approach of java datastore emulator available at [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/java/datastore/src/main/java/com/google/datastore/v1/client/DatastoreEmulator.java).